# Puppeteer - assign data to outside variable await page.on('response')

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

```
let data;
await page.on('response', async (response) => {

    if (response.url().includes("https://www.ubereats.com/api/getFeedV1")) {
        const j = await response.json();
        console.log(j);
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

This is a code segment of a web scraper with a puppeteer library.
Inside this `await`, I can log the `j` variable. But I need to assign it to the `data` variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Can you just say `data = await response.json()` ?

Comment: `page.on` is synchronous so there's nothing to `await`. It registers a callback. If you want to wait until the callback fires, you have to promisify the callback or use `waitForResponse`. The other option is putting your `data`-dependent code inside the callback chain directly.

Comment: thank you all. @ggorlen I have followed your way and got success. thank you.

Comment: Awesome--feel free to share a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @ggorlen said I have used the following method.

```
const responseData = (page, url) => {
               return new Promise(resolve => {
                   page.on("response", async (response) => {
                       if (response.url().includes(url)) {
                           const json = await response.json();
                           // console.log(json);
                           resolve(json);
                       }
                   });
               });
           }
   
let data = await responseData(page, "https://www.example.com/api/getFeedV1");
```